# A component is successfully executed but returns no output - Vertex AI Pipelines

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I built a Vertex AI pipeline and its first 3 steps are based on the same component. I ran the pipeline and the first 3 steps are all successfully executed in sequence. However, the 4th step was not executed due to an error saying the output of previous step cannot be found. How can this happen when the 3rd step was successfully executed and should return a string. Details below:

Component:

```
@component(packages_to_install=["numpy", "pandas", "google-cloud-bigquery", "pandas-gbq", "google-cloud-storage", "PyYAML"])
def deduplicate(project_id: str, config_path: str, bucket: str, product: str) -> str:
    ...
    
    return config_path
```

Pipeline:

```
@pipeline(name=PIPELINE_NAME, pipeline_root=PIPELINE_ROOT)
def pipeline(project_id: str, bucket: str, config_path: str):
    
    step_0 = deduplicate(project_id=project_id, config_path=config_path, bucket=bucket, product='x')
    step_1 = deduplicate(project_id=project_id, config_path=step_0.output, bucket=bucket, product='y')
    step_2 = deduplicate(project_id=project_id, config_path=step_1.output, bucket=bucket, product='z')
    
    step_3 = union_all(project_id=project_id, config_path=step_2.output, bucket=bucket, source_tables=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Error message:
Failed to find property "output:Output" associated with task "Project number: xxx, Job id: xxx, Task id: -xxx, Task name: deduplicate-3, Task state: SUCCEEDED, Execution name: projects/xxx/locations/us-central1/metadataStores/default/executions/xxx".

Screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKVsd.png)

I expect step_3 to be executed since step_0 and step_1 have returned outputs normally.

Comment: Can you check the returned outputs of the functions 0 and 1? maybe the 2nd vaue is not correct?

Comment: The outputs of step_0 and step_1 were the same, which is the config path passed in the pipeline. Actually I ran the pipeline again, and this time step_0 to step_3 are all successfully executed but step_4 (not shown in the pipeline definition) was not triggered. Such a random behaviour.

Comment: what error did you hit in `union_all`?

Comment: @JohnChang - did you get the solution to it?

Comment: @Riturajkumar Yes, I compiled the pipeline as a YAML file instead of JSON and it worked.

Comment: @JohnChang - Thank you for providing this information.

Comment: @JohnChang - Did you face or have worked on any similar issue like this one -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77391156/custom-labels-in-vertex-ai-pipeline-pipelinejobschedule